# Get messages from a queue only retrieves a single message

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I've created an azure service bus and a new logic-app using a manual trigger. I then add a "Get messages from a queue (peek-lock)" action to the app and set the maximum message count to "20".

I then create 5 new messages in my queue an manually and then trigger my new logic-app. When I then look at the execution of my app, I only see that ONE message was retrieved (and checked, that 4 messages are still in my queue).

Seems like the count of "20" is not being honored. I also checked the settings of my service-bus queue and the "Maximum Delivery Count" is set to "10". This should at least give me batches of 10 (instead of 20).

What am I missing?

Comment: One clarification about `"Maximum Delivery Count" is set to "10"`: It means that a message will be processed a maximum of 10 times before it is deadlettered i.e. sent to dead letter subqueue.

Comment: In a queueClient scenario you can set the OnMessageOptions.MaxConcurrentCalls to 5 ( for example) it will create 5 different threads for as many messages. not sure if this would work in the case of a logic app.

Answer (score -1):

It is not that simple to answer without more details. Still I hope this could help.

If you are using a WebJob, make sure associated AzureWebJobsStorage is created in Classical Mode, instead of Remote Mode. That would make your WebJob crash in less than 20 seconds... not reading all queue messages.

Does your logical-app involve a ServiceBusTrigger ? Then it seems like the first call to your method marked with correct trigger fails with exception, and that other messages are not read.

Let me know if I did misunderstood some details.